# Does WCN (Windows Connect Now) work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I'm trying to add a Canon printer wirelessly and I can't just enter the WEP settings, I'm forced to use this WCN which it says is in Vista, but I'm not finding it on Windows 7.

Where can I find this in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's still there: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-connect-now